# Cannot Modify Header Information - While trying logging in

Tags: debug, wp-blog-header.php

I am having the same issue as cited on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80276/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-theme-specific-functi

Can you give me a help on that.

I am using Optimize Press Theme

This is the error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/talent31/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/general-template.php:2102) in /home/talent31/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/option.php on line 568
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/talent31/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/general-template.php:2102) in /home/talent31/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/option.php on line 569

Comment: Add [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) information to your Question and try this [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) steps.

Answer (score 1):

`wp-includes/general-template.php:2102` is the function `wp_admin_css()`.
On the login page this function is called in `login_header()`.
Your theme or some plugin trys to send an HTTP header after that, probably during the actions `login_enqueue_scripts` or `login_head`.

`wp-includes/option.php on:569` is in function `wp_user_settings()`; a cookie is set here. Cookies are HTTP headers, so that cannot work when there was already some output.

Search for something like …

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'some_function_name' );
```

… and the registered callback function is probably calling `wp_user_settings()`.